# How to manage a collapsable list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="Collapsable">item 1</span>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="Collapsable">item 1.1</span></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I want a collapsable list with children that slide up and down. I have found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5Q8rJ/) snippet.

The result is similar as what I want but I need the slide effect. If I insert a duration of the effect the children work fine but this effect is reproduced also in the parent of the list.

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: You need to show the code that causes the problem

Answer (score 0):

try this one

http://jsfiddle.net/5Q8rJ/202/

```
$(".Collapsable").click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('Collapsed')){
        $(this).parent().find('> ul').slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass("Collapsed");
    }else{
        $(this).parent().find('> ul').slideDown();
        $(this).addClass("Collapsed");
    }
});

$(".Collapsable").each(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('ul').hide();
});
```